Unable to Retrieve Project Using projectByDataManagementAPIId in Autodesk AEC Data Model API
I'm using the Autodesk AEC Data Model Explorer to retrieve a project by its Data Management API project ID. Specifically, I'm attempting to use the projectByDataManagementAPIId query to fetch the project's details.
Here is the GraphQL query I'm using:
query Get {
  projectByDataManagementAPIId(dataManagementAPIProjectId:"b.b1932870-41d1-4010-a97b-fa25d807217f") {
    id
    name
  }
}

However, when I execute this query, I receive the following error message:
{
  "data": {
    "projectByDataManagementAPIId": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "The following ID is malformed: b.b1932870-41d1-4010-a97b-fa25d807217f.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 18
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "projectByDataManagementAPIId"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "correlation_id": "f3aa9769-9680-4e57-96b4-ef1159945ddf",
        "code": "BAD_REQUEST",
        "errorType": "UNAVAILABLE",
        "errorDetail": "SERVICE_ERROR"
      }
    }
  ],
  "extensions": {
    "pointValue": {
      "requestedQueryPointValue": 10
    }
  }
}

I..

Ensured that b.b1932870-41d1-4010-a97b-fa25d807217f is the correct project ID obtained from the Data Management API.
Tried using the ID without the extra b. prefix (b1932870-41d1-4010-a97b-fa25d807217f), but received a similar error stating the ID is malformed.
Attempted using just the GUID part (1932870-41d1-4010-a97b-fa25d807217f), but the error persisted.
Encoded the ID in base64, but still encountered the same error.


Sadly, the feature is only available for MFG Data API and not AEC Data Model API https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/mfgdatamodel-publicbeta/v2/reference/queries/projectbydatamanagementapiid/
There is a wishlist ticket logged with ID AECDATA-943 for the same
